# Why does the error occur after the Flutter Clean command?

Tags: flutter

After using the Flutter Clean command, packages cannot be found and too many errors appear.

After running the "flutter pub get" command, the problems are corrected.
It wasn't like this before, what could be the reason for this?

Flutter 2.0.2 • channel stable •
Framework • revision 8962f6dc68 (6 days ago) • 2021-03-11 13:22:20 -0800
Engine • revision 5d8bf811b3
Tools • Dart 2.12.1

[image: After flutter clean]

Comment: Maybe because now `flutter clean` may be removing the cached dependencies as well whereas before didn't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Flutter clean removes all cached packages which your IDE depends on for code completion. So that is why after running `flutter pub get` everything goes back to normal as the command re-downloads all the package files the IDE depends on.

Answer (score 2):

Just run `flutter pub get` after `flutter clean` Command.

By doing that dependencies on `pubspec.yaml` file will be updated as well as flutter and dark SDK dependencies.